# Assert that a list of strings contains a string ignoring case

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

I'm using Hamcrest matchers to assert that a list of strings contains a string, ignoring the case. My code is as follows:

```
assertThat("myList has the string", myList, Matchers.hasItem(Matchers.equalToIgnoringCase(string)));
```

But my java compiler is complaining about this line:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method assertThat(java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? super java.lang.Object>>)
```

Could anyone help me out with this error?

Thanks.

Comment: I think `assertThat` only takes two parameters; you're passing three.

Comment: assertThat can take in a reason for failure as well.

Comment: That line compiles for me.  Which version of Java are you using?  Which version of the Hamcrest and JUnit JARs are you using as well? (I'm using Java 8 update 122, hamcrest-all 1.3 and JUnit 4.12.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `equalToIgnoringCase`:

```
assertThat("Has potential promotion", b2BCartPage.getPromotionTexts(), hasItem(equalToIgnoringCase(messages.getString("cart.promotion.attention"))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own matcher:

```
package com.melorriaga.movies.common;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Factory;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class CaseInsensitiveSubstringMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<String> {

    private final String subString;

    private CaseInsensitiveSubstringMatcher(final String subString) {
        this.subString = subString;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(final String actualString) {
        return actualString.toLowerCase().contains(this.subString.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description) {
        description.appendText("containing substring \"" + this.subString + "\"");
    }

    @Factory
    public static Matcher<String> containsIgnoringCase(final String subString) {
        return new CaseInsensitiveSubstringMatcher(subString);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    assertThat("myList has the string", myList, hasItem(containsIgnoringCase("b")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will give [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-quick-start.html) a try.

```
@Test
void containsIgnoreCase() {
    List<String> given = Arrays.asList("Alpha", "Beta");

    assertThat(given).anyMatch(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase("alpha"));
    // if you favor method references over lamdas
    assertThat(given).anyMatch("alpha"::equalsIgnoreCase);
}
```

Big plus for assertj is that you can easily use code completion.